# Unlock a wallet address for use in smart contracts

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, smart-contract-wallets

I want to unlock my wallet address for use in Smart Contracts.
I’ve already done it on Ganache Cli on a forked chain but I don’t know how to do it on the mainnet.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "Unlock a wallet address" - ar you running a Go Ethereum node.

Comment: Unlock it so that I can send and receive crypto to the address through a smart contract. I am not, do I need to?

Comment: There is no need to unlock wallets to use them with smart contracts. Download MetaMask and try it with any DeFi service like Aave.com

Comment: I have a wallet but I want to make use of the 1inch smart contract to execute trades using a program but I am unsure of how to do that on the real blockchain as in development I used a local forked blockchain and had to unlock the address I was using. What is the mainnet equivalent of doing this?

Comment: You sign any outgoing transaction locally in your developed application/script/etc. Private key comes from the settings file.